# How does one upload a photo to twitter with the API function POST statuses/update_with_media

Tags: .net, twitter, twitter-oauth

**[Update 2011-09-21 11:19]**
I've fixed one problem that was causing a problem and that was GMT/GMT+2
My local time is at GMT+2, and twitter is using GMT+0/UTC. This was causing a timestamp out of bounds error.

I've now fixed that problem and now facing the next problem:
  string(96) "{"request":"/1/statuses/update_with_media.json","error":"Could not authenticate with OAuth."}"

This is the request header generated through Themattharris PHP library (using curl):

```
 ["request_header"]=>
    string(587) "POST /1/statuses/update_with_media.json HTTP/1.1

User-Agent: themattharris' HTTP Client

Host: upload.twitter.com

Accept: */*

Authorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key="L9AWIB6jvxm3Req1XWHxJA", oauth_nonce="9e41eea04e2dcc2b67784b35c27d8740", oauth_signature="N2Y4YzYwMDg1YjBmZTA1NDgwNDdjOGY3MDI4YjdiNWE3M2E5ZTA5YQ%3D%3D", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_timestamp="1316596483", oauth_token="373846001-bJYH4C47vk34yfIH3XbpvvfZjd2JrIX9OlO5MyO2", oauth_version="1.0"

Content-Length: 10024

Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----------------------------3ddd9c41c091



"
```

I am fairly sure that I used the correct secrets (copy-pastaed from the twitter dev pages of my application) There I also generated my private secret token

**[Update 2011-09-21 ~10:45]**
So I've got around using a PHP lib (rewritten to C++/CLI) and my C++ lib now produces the exact same results as the PHP Lib. (The Authorization header string).

For some reason I keep getting a status:(401) Unauthorized.
I am using System.Net.WebClient to make the request. And using UploadValues to, well upload the values.

If I use something like UploadData or using WebRequest instead of WebClient I get a Status:(500) Internal Server error.

I can provide all the strings and headers that I generate if needed (but I of course won't give out the secrets)

This is for example what my basestring and authorization string look like:

> BaseString:
>   POST&https%3A%2F%2Fupload.twitter.com%2F1%2Fstatuses%2Fupdate_with_media.json&oauth_consumer_key%3DL9AWIB6jvxm3Req1XWHxJA%26oauth_nonce%3Ddb0ca1f6c926c1d3ae0d9cbb2c349ae2%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D1316538778%26oauth_token%3D373846001-bJYH4C47vk34yfIH3XbpvvfZjd2JrIX9OlO5MyO2%26oauth_version%3D1.0
>
> Authorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key="L9AWIB6jvxm3Req1XWHxJA",
>   oauth_nonce="db0ca1f6c926c1d3ae0d9cbb2c349ae2",
>   oauth_signature="OGI4ZDVkYjZjNjA3YWMyZGYxNWYzZDBhNDE0ODcwMzRkMDE4OWZiYQ%3D%3D",
>   oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_timestamp="1316538778",
>   oauth_token="373846001-bJYH4C47vk34yfIH3XbpvvfZjd2JrIX9OlO5MyO2",
>   oauth_version="1.0"

---

Below is the old text, which is not valid any more.

---

I might be a simple question, but I just can't figure this out.
I am using [Twitterizer](http://www.twitterizer.net/) to get me the required secret tokens. This library also provides a way to update your twitter with a new tweet, but it does not support the new update_with_media call.

I've tried several ways, one way by using WebRequest and the other way by using WebClient (pseudo-C#-code):

```
string URL = "https://upload.twitter.com/1/statuses/update_with_media.json?oauth_consumer_secret=[mysecretgoeshere]&oauth_token_secret=[usersecretgoeshere]";
System.Net.ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
Byte[] fileData = File.ReadAllBytes(pathToFile);

#if useWebRequest
    string postString = "status={statusgoeshere}&image[]={Encoding.ASCII.GetString(fileData)}";
    Byte[] postData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postString);

    WebRequest wr = WebRequest.Create(URL);

    wr.Method = "POST";
    wr.ContentType = "multipart/form-data"; //as required by twitter API
    wr.ContentLength = postData.Length;

    IO.Stream rqstream = wr.GetRequestStream();
    rqstream.Write(postData,0,postData.Length);
    rqstream.Close();

    wr.GetResponse(); //returns status 500 internal server error
#else
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    NameValueCollection postData = new NameValueCollection();

    postData.Add("status", "{statusgoeshere}");
    postData.add("media[]", Encoding.ASCII.GetString(fileData));

    client.UploadValues(URL, "POST", postData); //returns status 401 not authorized
#endif
```

I wonder what I am doing wrong (if I am doing something wrong that is). Both ways seem valid in my eyes, but I might be missing some things.

Edit1:
I've noticed I am passing the oath parameters in the wrong way, will try and update that part.

Comment: I've updated the question with more and newer relevant information.

Comment: OAuth secret values are not sent over the internet. They are used to generate a signature (along with all the other querystring and/or form values).

Comment: @RickySmith yeah, I've found that out after working through the tmhOAuth PHP library ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that I haven't added any file uploads to Twitterizer yet is because it requires modification of the WebRequestBuilder class (that adds the OAuth header and signs requests) to handle multipart POST requests. I have attempted to make the needed modifications to this class a few times, but each time they resulted in instability in the rest of the library, mostly due to lack of documentation on how the Twitter API expects multipart requests to be signed.

Somewhat recently, however, a document was posted to the [Twitter API portal](https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/1059) detailing these requests. If you want to try to implement this logic on your own, that will be an invaluable resource. Otherwise, you can wait. I plan on making the modifications soon to properly support file uploads in light of this information.

Comment: I indeed started working on altering the code for Twitterizer to implement the with_media API. If I get things working I'll respond here again.

Comment: Right, what I've done is just added the Multipart - settings. Adding some if(Multipart) and if(!Multipart) in PrepareRequest function and adding a function to get the post-data as a multipart byte[]. This results in the following error: A first chance exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.dll
----------- RESPONSE -----------
{"request":"\/1\/statuses\/update_with_media.json","error":"Could not authenticate with OAuth."}
----------- END ----------- Bah, when I post a normal tweet it works fine. :-/

Comment: Right. That almost certainly means there is an issue with the OAuth signature generation. https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/1059 and http://www.oauth.net/ will have everything you need in the most boring format imaginable.

Comment: The thing is, I am not changing anything at all regarding the signature generation. Totally nothing!

Comment: Might it be something to do with generating the basestring in GenerateSignature? When posting the image the nonSecretParameters will include the status & image[] data that will be posted as multipart. I suppose it only needs to hash the status when it is using the status in the url-query-string?

Comment: I've fixed the problem. the generatesignature was including all paarameters except for the secret ones. I put an extra if(Multipart) around them where one LinQ query selects non-secret the other one selects non-secret and non-post data. That fixed it and it is now working great! Want me to send you the files somehow on how I've put things together? (I'll probably be able to do this after the weekend since I am now going home :-))

Comment: Please do! ricky [at] twitterizer.net

Answer (score 1):

Just in case anyone is still trying to upload on Twitter.
I am the main developer of Tweetinvi which is capable of uploading files for more than 6 months now.

Feel free to take a look at it:

Examples :

```
// 1 line to upload and publish
var tweet = Tweet.PublishTweetWithVideo("my tweet", File.ReadAllBytes("filepath"));

// OR WITH ADDITIONAL PARAMETERS
var uploadedVideo = Upload.UploadVideo(File.ReadAllBytes("filepath"));
tweet = Tweet.PublishTweet("my tweet", new PublishTweetOptionalParameters
{
    Medias = new List<IMedia> { uploadedVideo },
    Coordinates = new Coordinates(42, 42)
});
```

Obviously you can do more. 
Feel free to check the documentation : https://github.com/linvi/tweetinvi/wiki/Upload.

Answer (score 0):

[The TweetIt example](http://cheesoexamples.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=TweetIt) shows how update status and post an image via update_with_media.xml, via a .NET app written in C#.

Full source is available.  It does not use Twitterizer.  It uses [this Oauth module](https://cropperplugins.svn.codeplex.com/svn/Cropper.Plugins/TwitPic/OAuth.cs) for managing the authentication.

Comment: I've resolved the issue and changed the twitterizer code and Ricky updated the official Twitterizer, see the topic here: http://forums.twitterizer.net/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=607#p2139 but thanks for your information.

Answer (score 0):

Use, the tweetsharp Nuget plug in.

```
using (var stream = new FileStream(imagePath, FileMode.Open))
            {
                var result = service.SendTweetWithMedia(new SendTweetWithMediaOptions
                {
                    Status = message,
                    Images = new Dictionary<string, Stream> { { "john", stream } }
                });
                lblResult.Text = result.Text.ToString();
            }
```

The complete details are available at this article

Thanks

http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/show/3196/post-message-with-image-on-twitter-using-csharp